Variable length CBC MAC with hash appended
Multiple sources (including this paper from Bellare) claim that there are only 3 ways to make the variable length CBCMAC secure -1) input-length key separation, 2) prepending length 3) encrypt the last block. This seems to imply that any other variable length CBCMAC is insecure.
Can someone explain why the following construction is insecure? CBCMAC'(M) = CBCMAC(M||H(M)) where H is a secure hash function.
I attempted to do an attack similar to what you would do for appending the message-length, but the catch is that for message length, you can change some intermediate blocks and still have the same message length as the last block, so you can do some XOR cancellations to present a new message with the same tag. But when you append the hash, changing intermediate blocks changea the value of the last block input, so I don't see how you can reuse a tag unless you specifically find a collision to implement that attack.
I am specifically thinking about security in an UF-CMA sense, but if it makes sense to discuss under other notions, please point those out as well.

The biggest drawback is the second pass of the data. Proving is a long process...

Not sure what you mean by that?? Can you be a little clearer?
